# Load AJAX data into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to create Two Tables Parent / Child as in this example.
https://datatables.net/blog/2016-03-25
I'm running in Laravel framework.

My problem is that when i wont to load the Ajax data it doesn't work.

```
var siteTable = $('#sites').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',

    **ajax: '{{asset('AJAXDATA.PHP')}}',**

    columns: [
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'users', render: function ( data ) {
            return data.length;
        } }
    ],
    select: {
        style: 'single'
    },
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'create', editor: siteEditor },
        { extend: 'edit',   editor: siteEditor },
        { extend: 'remove', editor: siteEditor }
    ]
} );
```

I'm also trying

```
**ajax: '{{asset('AJAXDATA.PHP')}}',**
**ajax: '{{asset('AJAXDATA.TXT')}}',**
**ajax: '{{route('ajaxdata')}}',**
```

Yes, the files AJAXDATA.PHP and AJAXDATA.TXT are in my root folder and it opens with no problem.
And the route ajaxdata returns the data as the same file in ajaxdata.php

So, how can I load the data from ajax this way?
Thaks

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you've added the `**` in the code just to point out where it is? Or do you have it in the actual code? Also, when something doesn't work, please explain what actually happens. Wrong data? Errors in the console? Errors in the web servers error log? Does it actually make a request to the server (check this by looking at the network tab in the browsers dev tools while you're making the request)? You say that the file is in your root folder, is that  the URL that the code generates? Check "view source" in the browser and see it the URL is correct.

Comment: ** for point the code. The page load with empty tables. It seems that dons't make any request to the server, becouse you can open route ajaxdata and returns previus data as expected, but not in the table.